# Facebook SDK Test Users

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk

I've been rejected around 7 times now because "my app crashes" when the Facebook review team tries to "share" to facebook.

I'm writing an Android Camera app that will have facebook integration by allowing the user to upload a photo they took directly to facebook.

For my submission, I'm trying to gain the "publish_actions" permission which requires the facebook review team to pass my app first. Here's my problem: How can I allow the facebook review team to share to facebook without this permission. I've been told to setup test users (which I have done). But that's all I have done. Do I need to get some account tokens or something for the test user etc? Is that required? Right now, I just allow the user to login to facebook, and I wait until it's time to share to request the publish_actions permission. But this is where the review team is saying that the app is crashing. For me it does NOT crash because I'm the developer and I have the permission. So how can I work this out. :) I'm app is done. I just need facebook to say "OK!" :) Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Just to re-iterate, I only allow the user to login to facebook with the facebook button, then When it's time to share, I request the "publish_actions" permission (which obviously get denied) then the app crashes (for the facebook review team, not me. Works great on my end).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the answer is not with the Test Users.

Solution to the problem:

When specifying test users for the facebook review team, make sure to use the facebook LoginButton (View) directly to request permissions. (I.E. mFacebookLoginButton.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions")); For some reason, this allows me to setup the button that will request the permission in the future "when the user actually presses the button."

It's kind of like attaching the permission request to the button, so that when it is finally pressed, it will execute the request at the same time.

I know they say don't do this at login time, but honestly it's the only way I could get the permission to work (for a test user.) (Also works for normal users "after the permission has been approved by the facebook review team.)